# Apache Camel: how do I dynamically insert data after from?

Tags: java, sql, apache-camel

There is sql:

```
private static final String MARS_SQL_TEMPLATE_TWO = "select\n" +
            " id_delivery_area,\n" +
            " id_country,\n" +
            " id_gate_sites_group,\n" +
            " free_shipping_bill,\n" +
            " id_territory,\n" +
            " price,\n" +
            " id_mtt_type,\n" +
            " id_gt_service_level,\n" +
            " extract (hour from delivery_trigger_time)\n" +
            " ||':'\n" +
            " ||extract (minute from delivery_trigger_time)\n" +
            " delivery_trigger_time,\n" +
            " delivery_period_to_hours,\n" +
            " delivery_period_from_days,\n" +
            " delivery_period_to_days,\n" +
            " '%s' as brand,\n" +
            " '%s' as country\n" +
            " from :param ";
```

In place of :param I want to add a value, during the route call:

```
List<MarsDeliveryArea> finalList = (List<MarsDeliveryArea>) routeService.executeRoute(MARS_ROUTE, "param", b);

   public Object executeRoute(String endpointName, String headerKey, Object headerValue) {
        val template = DefaultFluentProducerTemplate.on(camelContext);
        if (headerKey != null) template.withHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
        return template.to("direct://" + endpointName).request();
    }
```

It doesn't work.

How can I do this? Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

End your template immediately after "... from " and use something like the below in your route, perhaps?

```
.to("sql:" + MARS_SQL_TEMPLATE_TWO + ":#${header.param}")
```